# Behaviour of order in the range over map in this Golang program

Tags: go, fizzbuzz

I am a beginner programmer and was going through some GitHub repositories and found this simple classic `fizzbuzz` [implementation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jashanj0tsingh/GoTutorials/master/FizzBuzz.go) using a map. However when I run it a couple of times it prints `buzzfizz` when the `isMultiple` is `true` for both `3` and `5`. For instance, once in a while for the values `15` or `60` it may print `buzzfizz` instead of `fizzbuzz` which seems inconsistent to me and got me curious to fix it. Can someone explain why does this happen and what I am missing here? Is it merely a language behavior or the code can be improved for this consistency?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func isMultiple(i,j int)bool  {
    return i%j==0
}
func main(){
    fizzbuzz:=make(map[int]string)
    fizzbuzz[3]="fizz"
    fizzbuzz[5]="buzz"
    for i:=1; i<101; i++ {
        str:=""
        for k,v:=range fizzbuzz{
            if isMultiple(i,k)==true{str+=v}
        }
        fmt.Println(i,":",str)
    }

}
```

Edit: Decided to put the code here seeing the common convention it is better here.

Comment: No one can explain this without seeing the code.

Comment: maps are unordered data structures, so their iteration order is not deterministic.

Comment: Not about your question, but stylistically "isMultiple(i,k)==true" should be rewritten as "isMultiple(i,k)"

Answer (score 2):

Go maps are unordered data structures, you should not rely on ordering of keys.

To prevent developers from accidentally relying on small map ordering, Go randomizes small maps every time.

Please [read up](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) on maps in Go.

Comment: See also [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements): "The iteration order over maps is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next."